# Windows 8 phone, multi tab browser not updating current url

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8, tabs, browser

I am in the process of making a multi tab browser and have run into some problems. I would like it so when the user has added a new tab using a button, that every site they then choose to navigate to will update to the tab url. So if the user changes tab or opens a new one, it the last website will be saved if they return to the previous tab.

Here is the code while creating a new tab & When a tab is selected from the created ones

```
private void addNewTab(string url)
{
    TabEntry urlObj = new TabEntry();
    urlObj.URL = url;
    urlObj.timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
    if (url.Contains("/"))
    {
        urlObj.Name = url.Remove(url.IndexOf('/'));
    }
    else
    {
        urlObj.Name = url.Remove(url.IndexOf('.'));
    }

    tabs.Insert(0, urlObj);

    listBoxTabPage.ItemsSource = null;
    listBoxTabPage.ItemsSource = tabs;

    Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute));
    //selectedTab = listBoxTabPage.SelectedValue as TabEntry;
    }

    private void ListBoxTabPage_SelectionChanged(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedTab = listBoxTabPage.SelectedValue as TabEntry;
        Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www." + selectedTab.URL, UriKind.Absolute));
        PivotItems.SelectedItem = BrowserPage;
    }
```

Here is the code where it should update the selected tabs url, in the Browser_Navigated methord

```
void Browser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _deactivatedURL = e.Uri;
    _progressIndicator.IsVisible = false;

    string url = Convert.ToString(e.Uri);

    //selectedTab.URL = url;
    addHistoryRecord(url);
```

}

Where it is commented out I think is the problem. I believe the code does not know which one is the selectedTab. To fix this error should I create a methord which updates the url of the tab, each time the browser navigates. And how would the program know which tab is currently in use.

If you need any more details please comment and I will be happy to explain in further detail.

Answer (score 2):

You just set `listBoxTabPage.ItemsSource = null` before you set tabs as `ItemsSource`. It may clears your `listBoxTabPage.SelectedValue`.

I think you can just set `listBoxTabPage.SelectedValue = urlObj` in `addNewTab()`.

Then you begin navigate to a new uri in `ListBoxTabPage_SelectionChanged`, but it seems to be wrong that you just append a prefix string `http://www.` to an full url. It may triggers `NavigateFailed` event if you navigate to a non-exist website.

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www." + selectedTab.URL, UriKind.Absolute));
```

What's more, `ListBoxTabPage_SelectionChanged` may triggers twice because the old value is cleared and the new value is set.